# Data type mismatch in criteria expression using Access via ODBC

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

```
$conn=odbc_connect('mobshopDB','','');
    if(!$conn){
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $query="INSERT INTO users(uid,pass,fname,lname,pmm) VALUES('$username','$password','$fname','$lname',$pmm)";
    $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$query);
```

this query gives me this error

`Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression., SQL state 22005 in SQLExecDirect in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\mobshop\registered.php on line 39`

..please suggest a solution

NOTE: pmm is a numeric field, thats why i haven't put it in quotes.

Comment: Need table structure to be able to answer this questions accurately.

Answer (score 1):

"Data Type Mismatch" indicates that you are trying to pass in an incorrect data type in one of your variables for one of the fields listed in your first set of parenthesis.

Try writing $query to the screen using echo and then take that result and run it in your MS Access database query designer (assuming you have the MS Access software).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of This

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(uid,pass,fname,lname,pmm) VALUES('$username','$password','$fname','$lname',$pmm)";
```

Try This

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(uid,pass,fname,lname,pmm) VALUES('$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$pmm')";
```

You just forget single quote in $pmm field. Remember if you are using ODBC then be careful with datatype.

If the value will be an integer then do Type casting of value like this  
`$id = (int) $id;`

If Datatype is not Integer then you must put single quotes