# odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression., SQL state 22005 in SQLExecDirect

Tags: php, database, odbc, ms-access-2007

Fetch data Microsoft Access database in PHP Using ODBC. when Run Query Execute then give Error:

> odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data
>   type mismatch in criteria expression., SQL state 22005 in
>   SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\Attend.php on line 21

`Connection.php` run give Message Connect. when `$stmt = odbc_exec($conn, $sql)` is run give above warning. What's Problem I don't.

**Connection.php**

```
<?php

$conn = odbc_connect("$dbq","",""); 
if($conn){
    echo "Connected";

}else{

    echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

**Attend.php**

```
<?php

include 'Connection.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST["insert"]))
{
    $reg = $_GET['reg'];
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];

    $sql = "select a.RegNo,b.RollNo,c.Standard,d.Division,b.Std_Name as StudentName,AttendanceDate,Attendance_Type,Remark
                                         from (((Attendance_mas as a 
                                         inner join Std_Reg as b on a.RegNo = b.RegNo) 
                                         inner join StandardMaster as c on a.Standard = c.stdid)
                                         inner join DivisionMaster as d on a.Division =d.DivisionID)
                                         where a.RegNo= '$reg' and a.yearid = '$ID' Order by AttendanceDate desc";
    //$sql = "select * from Std_Reg";

    $stmt = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    //print_r($stmt);
    $result = [];
    do {
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){
           $result[] = $row; 
        }
    } while (odbc_next_result($stmt));

    if(count($result)>0)
    {
        $result1['status']=1;//"Login successfully";
        array_push($result1,$result);
    }
    else
    {
         //$result[]="null";
        $result1['status']=0;//"Record not found";
        array_push($result1,$result);
    }
    odbc_free_result($stmt);
    odbc_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

    echo json_encode($result1); //You will get the encoded array variable
}

?>
```

Comment: Refere this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751823/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-using-access-via-odbc

Comment: Refer this link ago,but this link not give result